# mysql_connect to Remote Server from local machine

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm trying develop on my local machine, while using one database on my remote server.

To do this I've tried changing the myql_connect line.

from

```
$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "pw");
```

to

```
$con = mysql_connect("mydomain.com:2082", "username", "pw");
```

and now I'm getting the following errors

> Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has
>   gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\posts\index.php on line 27 Warning:
>   mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: Error while reading greeting
>   packet. PID=5092 in C:\xampp\htdocs\posts\index.php on line 27
>   Warning: mysql_connect() [function.mysql-connect]: MySQL server has
>   gone away in C:\xampp\htdocs\posts\index.php on line 27 Fatal error:
>   Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\posts\index.php on line 27

I don't really understand what the :2082 is or what it does. In the examples on the php page it uses :3307, but when I log into cpanel on my remote server it always has :2082 after my domain name. In any case 3307 doesn't work either.

Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong? (or should I be doing something different -- like changing the mysql default host somewhere in the php.ini[??] and then continue to use `local` host in the `mysql_connect`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: the `:2082` should be the port number where mysql is listening for connections. That's weird as it is usually 3306. Try to telnet to port 2082 to make sure it's indeed listening on that port.

Comment: Just to clarify, have you set that the webserver accepts external connections?

Comment: the :2082 is the port you are connecting to on the specified hostname. The default MySQL port is 3306. I would suggest a) completely omit the port and allow it to connect to the default port b) ask your hosting provider for the correct connection details.

Comment: The default port that MySQL listens for connections is `3306`. The `2082` (which is probably the port that CPanel is listening to) is totally unrelated.

Comment: I think 2082 is the port that cPanel uses, however it shouldn't be the same for mysql

Comment: I have allowed the webserver to accept connections - I will now try port 3306

Comment: Go to `Remote MySQL` add `%.%.%.%` and give us your webhost IP.

Comment: ha the answer is port 3306 - I don't how I would figure that out without everybody's help. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

That `:2082` is the port which mySQL is trying to connect to. It however, **will not** be the same port as your cPanel. `:3307` is the port mySQL traditionally listens on.

I don't use cPanel much, but I believe it tends to set up a subdomain `mysql.yourdomain.com` that you can connect to.

Past that, make sure that you setup the mySQL user to be able to connect from your local machine.

Comment: `MySQL uses port 3306 by default.`

Answer (score 0):

Please contact to remote server administration and ask to give permission to your server IP address for access their database from your server/website.